# Why does running the script not show the file in the output folder correctly?

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, pca

Why does running the script not show the file in the output folder correctly? The script was run in PyQGIS 3.10.
Below find the script used

```
import processing
import os

path ='DESCUELAJORNADA_CIENT_ALLclip_L8'
output = DESCUELAJORNADA_CIENT_ALLOUTPUT

bandList = [band for band in os.listdir(path) if band[-4:]=='.TIF']

input = [os.path.join(path,band)for band in bandList]

def pca_grass(input,output)
    processing.runAndLoadResults(grass7i.pca,
    {'-f': False,
     'n': False,
     'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':0,
     'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,
     'input': input,
     'output':output,
     'percent':99,
     'rescale':[0,400]})
    outList=[band for band in os.listdir(output) if band[-4:]=='.TIF']
    new_output = [ os.path.join(output,band) for band in outList ]
    for band in new_output
        iface.addRasterLayer(band,band)
pca_grass(input,output)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS.SE. Please, have a look at the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to give a little bit of context to your problem, especially by describing the software environment you're currently running your code in.

Comment: "Wall of code" questions tend to attract downvotes, since they're not really questions. Please [Edit] the question to include details of your task and software environment, and information about the error or other failure that occurs. *Then* go back and write a title that summarizes the issue (as opposed to being the only text in the question).

Comment: Probably, Darian Paz is same user than Manuel Guerra.

Comment: Permission, we are students who are working on the same research project, I think it is very bad that this is stated.

Comment: the problem is that for the first time we are in a forum of this type and we find the rules difficult